# SUBLIME TEXT 3 JAVA BUILD RESULT NOT WORKING

Tags: java, build, compilation, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a problem in sublime text 3. After successful build i am not getting output . even build result is not working for hello world java program and no output please help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aziph.png)

```
import java.io.*;
class h{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  System.out.println("Hello World"); }}
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aziph.png

Comment: Are you actually running the program?

Comment: @Ares
yes ..i need output below in sublime without using command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OS-WINDOWS** 
1. IN command palette , TYPE AND CLICK  install package
 2. INSTALL package resource viewer OR pvr

3.THEN COPY THIS CODE AND PASTE IN java sublime build file

{"cmd":["javac","$file_name","&&","java","$file_base_name"],"file_regex":"^(...?):([0-9]):?([0-9]*)","selector": "source.java","shell": true }

[YOUTUBE LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXDdhRH7J84)

Answer (score 4):

Building means you now have a program. In order to get output, you have to run it. To run it, find your h.class file and run:

```
java h
```

This should print the message you're looking for.

Also if you're having this sort of basic problem, it helps to narrow things down to figure out where the problem is coming from. For example you could have first tried without using Sublime Text at all, like this:

```
$ javac h.java
(nothing is printed but you should now have a h.class file)
$ java h
Hello World
```

If nothing else, this would make for a better StackOverflow question.

Comment: i need output in sublime below not using  command

Comment: Someone knowledgeable in Sublime (or whichever plugin lets you build Java programs) will have to help with that part. Did you try Ctrl-B? That's what Google tells me is the sublime shortcut for "run" (can't test it for you though).

Comment: yes i hv did ......i got my output see my answer below how its done  thank u :)